# Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to create an app in android studio using kotlin and I get the error "Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'"
My code of the problem block looks like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("")
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    val googleLoginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.google_login_btn)
    googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
        signIn()
    }
}
```

I tried many ways but nothing helped, I hope this problem will be solved